# Maxima of sum of two functions

Tags: convex-optimization, maxima-minima

Is there any relationship between the locations of local maximas of two different functions and the location of the maxima of their sum. That is, if
$$\alpha_1 = \arg \max f_1(\alpha)$$ and $$\alpha_2 = \arg \max f_2(\alpha),$$where that $\alpha_1 \ne \alpha_2$. Might there be any function $g(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ such that
$$\alpha_s = \arg \max (f_1(\alpha) + f_2(\alpha)) = g(\alpha_1,\alpha_2) ?$$

NB: $\alpha \in \mathcal{R}$, $f:\alpha \longrightarrow \mathcal{R}$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. Consider the following functions:
$$f_1(x)=-2|x|, \: f_2(x) = -2|x - 1|$$
$$g_1(x) = -x^2, \: g_2(x) = -(x-1)^2$$
Their maxima are pretty clear.

Where are the maxima of:
$$f_1 + f_2? \quad g_1 + g_2? \quad f_1 + g_2?$$

Note that:
$$\arg \max f_1(\alpha) = \arg \max g_1(\alpha) = 0$$
$$\arg \max f_2(\alpha) = \arg \max g_2(\alpha) = 1$$